# How can I add static HTML pages in the Azure Developer Portal to display some documentation text?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, portal, azureportal

I need to add pages (kind of static web pages) in Azure APIM Developer Portal to display documentation.  Is there any tutorial to explain how to achieve it? 
Is there a way I can read the text content from REST API calls and populate the pages in Dev portal?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and provide more detail about the expected outcome?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is more or less similar to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/78931/index.html) where you are trying to update documentation properly at Azure Api Managment developer portal.

In that case, as mentioned in the thread, you can try with swagger but in APIM portal it might not work immediately. Microsoft product team has confirmed that they working on improvig support for OpenAPIv3. The ETA is about end of September.

However, you may also check the [self-hosted gateway feature](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/selfhosted-gateway-feature-in-api-management-is-now-generally-available/)

> The self-hosted gateway feature expands API Management support for hybrid and multi-cloud environments and enables organizations to efficiently and securely manage APIs hosted on-premises and across clouds from a single API Management service in Azure.
> [Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/self-hosted-gateway-overview)